# JavaScript API call for "/me/friends" returns a response with empty list but correct summary

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I do the call:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) { console.log(response);});
```

I see in the console log response as and object with empty data and correct summary:

```
 Object { data=[0], summary={...}}
```

Where summary is (the number of my friends):

```
Object { total_count=444}
```

I know that friends edge call has been changed through APi v2.1. It works in Graph API explorer. I hve specified permissions for the requested operation before:

```
<fb:login-button scope="user_friends" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That means you don't have any friends. Get out, meet some people. #justbeinggoofy

Comment: Ok, on a serious note. Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m

Comment: @NickAllen this post relates to the API v2.0. In API v2.1 they changed this. It also works from the Graph API Explorer testbed. This works for likes, albums etc. Just doesn't work for friends.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand what the `user_friends` permission is for.  This is taken from the docs about the `user_friends` permission:

**user_friends**

Provides access the list of friends that also use your app. These friends can be found on the friends edge on the user object.

In order for a person to show up in one person's friend list, ***both people must have decided to share their list of friends with your app*** 
and not disabled that permission during login. Also both friends must have been asked for user_friends during the login process.

**Review**

Your app may use this permission without review from Facebook.

**Common Usage**

Use the list of friends to create a social experience in your app.

Comment: Thanks Phillip. Why does the Graph API Explorer show the full friends list upon executing the same command?

Comment: Explorer operates under different restrictions and capabilities.

Comment: In a way the Explorer is similar to Facebook itself. It serves no other purpose than to explore the API. In that regard it would be detrimental to limit its capability. I think they should explain not everything works the same in an app environment, but I hope that helps you understand why it is different.